# Insert list of Images after list of Paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of images, I want to insert one image after each paragraph. Sometimes I have less images than paragraphs sometimes more. How do I loop through the img elements to insert them after a paragraph, and if there are too much images, leave them where they are?

```
 $( ".img" ).insertAfter( "p" );
```

Without content the structure would look like this:

Before:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
</div>

<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
```

Result:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <img class="img" />
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <img class="img" />        
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <img class="img" />
</div>
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
<img class="img" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after) method:

```
var $img = $('.img');

$('#wrap p').after(function(i) { return $img.eq(i); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7tchk5r/